# Implement Firebase inside of a Library

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to implement Firebase notifications system inside a library that I want to use as SDK in many apps.

Firebase is asking now for an App ID, but I'm implementing it inside a library, thus no App Id.

How could I achieve my goal to be able to send notifications to my apps that use my library ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would think so by passing the App ID into the library via an initialization of the library from your main app.

Comment: Hey @Sekai if my answer did solve your problem please mark it as accepted (SO policy)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes you can actually do this, on your library `build.gradle` put this inside the defaultConfig field

```
buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_APP_KEY", "\"${firebaseAppKey}\"")
```

Then inside your project's `gradle.properties`

`firebaseAppKey = <yourFirebaseAppSecret>;`

For **each** project/app you must define this variable on your `gradle.properties`.

**You'll have to create a firebase app for each project**, but your library can now have the Firebase SDK.

When you want to access this environment variable value use `BuildConfig.FIREBASE_APP_KEY`
(e.g. instantiate firebase).

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that requires minimum manipulation from developers. We will try this and if it doesn't work, we'll try implementing sockets notifications

Comment: @Sekai I thinks having to only configure the gradle files is quite acceptable. If you pre-set your library like this I as a developer would be quite pleased. The only thing your "client" will need to do is create he's own Firebase app (no way around this) and use he's own key, this way the key won't be exposed anywhere, assuming you aren't uploading your `gradle.properties` (which you shouldn't).

Answer (score 22):

These are all kinda hacky or too much work, here’s a nice n simple example (ironic though, cause it’s a long post -- but worth it).

It is possible to use `FireBase` code in your library project, of course the consuming application will need to register the app and get the app ID / `google-services.json` file.

But your library doesn’t, and shouldn’t care about about that, it’s the consuming applications job to do that, not your library.

Here’s a brief example using the `firebase-messaging` module inside of a library project.

**YourLibrary module’s build.gradle**:

```
// Other typical library set up 
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'

        // Don’t for get your library’s proguard file!
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

ext {
    currentFirebaseVersion = "11.8.0"
}

dependencies {
    /* 
    Here we depend on the firebase messaging dependency (via compileOnly),
    allowing us to use the FireBase API within our library module.

    I exclude that org.json module because it may cause build warnings, this 
    step isn’t totally necessary.

    NOTE: You should use `compileOnly` here so the dependency is
    not added to the build output You will be allowed to use the 
    dependency in your library. If the consuming app wants to use firebase
    they’ll need to depend on it (using `implementation`).
    */
    compileOnly("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$currentFirebaseVersion") {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
}

// Other typical library set up. But nothing else relating Firebase.
```

This is all you need to do in your library project. **DON’T** apply the gms plug in here, and **don’t** add the google-services classpath to the libraries `build.gradle`.

Now here’s how you set up your consuming app:

**MyClientApp’s top-level build.gradle**:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() // You know the drill...
    }
    // Any other set up you might have...

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        /*
        Here in your client app’s top-level build.gradle you add the
        google-services to the app’s classpath.
        */
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
// Other basic stuff...
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Now we need to set up the consuming applications module `build.gradle`, it’s simple. We pretty much just need to apply the plug-in, and depend on the library module that we create that has all the `FireBase` code in it.

**MyClientApp’s module level build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.your.application.that.can.use.firebase"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    //other typical set up
}

ext {
    currentFirebaseVersion = "11.8.0"
}

dependencies {
    implementation('com.your.library:YourLibrary:1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
        // Use the consuming application's FireBase module, so exclude it
        // from the dependency. (not totally necessary if you use compileOnly
        // when declaring the dependency in the library project).
        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase'
        // Exclude the "plain java" json module to fix build warnings.
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$currentFirebaseVersion") {
        // Exclude the "plain java" json module to fix build warnings.
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
}

// Needs to be at the bottom of file.
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Some things to note:

- Must apply google-services plugin at the bottom (only in the client module `build.gradle`).
- Depend on the library module that has the `FireBase` code in it, but exclude it’s version of the `FireBase` module, in favor of your own dependency version.
- App depends on it's own `FireBase` version.
- `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1’` only goes in the client app’s top level `build.gradle`.
- Of course you will need to register the client app and put the `google-services.json` in your client app’s project.
- Define the necessary `Firebase` `Service`s in your app’s manifest (or use manifest merger and merge them in from your library project)
- Add the `google_play_services_version` meta-data tag to your client app’s Manifest.
- The library can/should use `compileOnly` when declaring the `FireBase` dependency.

Now you’ll be able to use `FireBase` code in your app that you defined in your library that uses `FireBase`. Or you could let your library module do all the `FireBase` work!

Of course this is typically used for internal libraries, as frameworks like `Firebase` weren’t designed to be implemented in library modules, but sometimes you need to, so this is a simple non-hacky/sane solution to the issue. It can be used on projects that are distributed through maven -- my library uses this, and it’s never caused any issues.

**Update:**

You should use `compileOnly` when declaring the library module's `Firebase` dependency. By doing so the dependency will not be added to the build output. But you will be allowed to use the dependency in your library. If the consuming app wants to use firebase they’ll need to depend on it manually (using `implementation`). This will help cut down on unneeded dependencies/bloat in applications and the “right” way to declare a dependency like this. **Note:** You may need to perform runtime checks to make sure the library is available before using it’s code in your module.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
Some note. I had a problem with `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'`. I got `Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)`
I had to roll back to version 3.2.1. Then it was compiled wll.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question with an accepted answer but all the answers have a big disadvantage - they require the user of your library to do work besides adding your library to their application. There is a way to do it **without troubling the user of your library at all** if your library is being downloaded from a Maven repository.

Note: this method is a hack and is not supported by Firebase. When asked Firebase Support, I got the following reply:

> **Firebase SDKs are not intended for library projects**. The features available on Firebase were integrated in an application level and not
>   on a per module or per library basis so, the use case for having this
>   integrated on a library project is not possible or not supported.

Nevertheless, I've found a way to do it and maybe someone will find it useful so here it is:

This is an example of using Realtime Database but it should work for all the Firebase SDKs.

In your project's main `build.gradle` add mavenCentral repository:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

In your library project's `build.gradle`, add Google Play Services (as a dependency, not as a plugin):

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
```

Add the relevant Firebase SDKs (with the same version as Google Play Services):

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
```

Register your SDK as a project on Firebase, download it's `google-services.json` and open it with any text editor.

In your library's `strings.xml` add the following lines and fill these lines with data from `google-services.json`

```
<string name="gcm_defaultSenderId">project_number</string>
<string name="google_api_key">current_key</string>
<string name="google_app_id">mobilesdk_app_id</string>
<string name="google_crash_reporting_api_key">current_key</string>
<string name="google_storage_bucket">storage_bucket</string>
<string name="firebase_database_url">firebase_url</string>
<string name="default_web_client_id">client_id</string>
<string name="project_id">project_id</string>
```

This is it. You can use Firebase Realtime Database in your libaray, then build it and publish it to Maven (publishing to Maven is essential, otherwise the user of your library will have to add the dependencies manually). When activated from inside an application, your database will be used.

Note that this method may cause exceptions and unexpected behavior if the user of your library will use Google Play Services or Firebase so **use at your own risk!**

Comment: I've tried this using the latest libraries (gcm 16.0.0, firebase-core 16.0.7). It's not working. Getting "Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found. This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your gradle project." and  "Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled." even if adding such strings both to library and app. Seems like there is no way to do this anymore without having to register the app in Firebase

Answer (score 7):

One option is to have the user of your library create a Firebase project and then pass in the resulting google-services.json file into their application then your library can depend on that.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase Multiple Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#java)

Please refer to the link it has all the information